# How can i show Album images Like Facebook post like this?

Tags: api, flutter, widget

I'm getting single images nor multiple images link from the API link according to the user uploads. So I want to create a Responsible widget. Which want to change according to the API data. If I get more than 4 images, I want to show the count like this. I mean over the images. please see the image mark below

[image: Wanted widget]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably create a widget to handle all that. Here is a small example.
This widget takes image Urls and puts them in a grid and when the number of images exceeds maxImages, It does that facebook stuff.

Tweak the widget according to your requirements.

```
import 'dart:math';

class PhotoGrid extends StatefulWidget {
      final int maxImages;
      final List<String> imageUrls;
      final Function(int) onImageClicked;
      final Function onExpandClicked;

  PhotoGrid(
      {@required this.imageUrls,
      @required this.onImageClicked,
      @required this.onExpandClicked,
      this.maxImages = 4,
      Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _PhotoGridState();
}

class _PhotoGridState extends State<PhotoGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var images = buildImages();

    return GridView(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2,
      ),
      children: images,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildImages() {
    int numImages = widget.imageUrls.length;
    return List<Widget>.generate(min(numImages, widget.maxImages), (index) {
      String imageUrl = widget.imageUrls[index];

      // If its the last image
      if (index == widget.maxImages - 1) {
        // Check how many more images are left
        int remaining = numImages - widget.maxImages;

        // If no more are remaining return a simple image widget
        if (remaining == 0) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Image.network(
              imageUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            onTap: () => widget.onImageClicked(index),
          );
        } else {
          // Create the facebook like effect for the last image with number of remaining  images
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => widget.onExpandClicked(),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    child: Text(
                      '+' + remaining.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      } else {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Image.network(
            imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          onTap: () => widget.onImageClicked(index),
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a small example of usage:

```
var urls = <String>[
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: PhotoGrid(
            imageUrls: urls,
            onImageClicked: (i) => print('Image $i was clicked!'),
            onExpandClicked: () => print('Expand Image was clicked'),
            maxImages: 4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result in dart pad:
Ignore the fact that I used the same image. When you click an image, appropriate functions are called too.

[image: Result - DartPad]

Comment: First of all thank, you man, I tried this answer, but the image is not visible, 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/arMkA.png

Comment: Try changing the network image to any of the asset images. Check if your emulator has access to the internet. Sometimes, I face similar problems with internet on my emulator, which is usually fixed by a restart. Tell me if it works.

Comment: yes, I already change the network image (  https://picsum.photos/250?image=9  ) and my emulator internet is working perfectly because I retrieve API data from my server

Comment: Thanks, man,**it's working fine**, it takes time to load, If you like my question, please vote.

Comment: I'm using this `PhotoGrid` inside the `Listview.builder()` here I'm facing one problem      
 1. **I can't scroll the `PhotoGrid` widget**, and  After user click the one photo user want to view the photo like Facebook, so if you can you please do it, it's a big help for me

Comment: Hello guys what we have to do if we have 3 images

Comment: @RavishSharma You mean 3 pics in a row?

Comment: yeah @AfridiKayal

Comment: like its working fine for one or two images ,but when it comes to three I want to show one image and below that two

Comment: can you please help me out @AfridiKayal

Comment: not in a row like in 3 case one will be full and another two will below

Comment: For 3 in a row, you can use GridView.count instead of using the GridView with grid delegate as SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent

Comment: wait I am sending you a snapshot so it will be easy for you what I want

Comment: I think you are looking for a staggered grid view. Check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: yes I have checked that as well but not able to set tiles count in dynamic way .

Comment: https://github.com/whatsupcoders/Flutter-Staggered-GridView/blob/master/lib/gridpage.dart

Comment: you can have a look above link which I followed  but the tiles are static for each image .in my case in feed some user might have two images some have 10

Comment: https://ibb.co/YtQKNTv please have a look on snapshot this is exactly I want @AfridiKayal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239802/discussion-between-afridi-kayal-and-ravish-sharma).