# How to open Image in full screen when we press on list of image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

> Here I actually use `GridView.builder` for load list of images. I want to add functionality like when I click on any particular image, it load and open in full screen. How is the possible in flutter?

Comment: I hope this might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708264/how-can-i-show-album-images-like-facebook-post-like-this/60711644#60711644)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best way but it does the job for me.
[Hero widget for multiple network images](https://dartpad.dev/97ac5d7ac6db486ceac4926c04473a31)

The idea is to assign unique hero tags to your images and create a widget for the next screen which dynamically assigns hero tag with the value passed through the constructor. Instead of changing tags for your images, change the tag for the hero widget on the next screen.

Comment: This should be the selected answer!